# Is there a way to read a Postgres array column as an array column in Julia DataFrames?

Tags: postgresql, dataframe, odbc, julia

I'm trying to read the output of a query from a Postgres database using the ODBC and DataFrames packages. Some of the columns are text array types in the database.

Here is a preview:

```
│ Row │ id                     │ name                     │ artist_ids               │ available_markets        │
│     │ String                 │ Union{Missing, String}   │ Union{Missing, String}   │ Union{Missing, String}   │
├─────┼────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤──────────────────────────┤──────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 69uJi5QsBtqlYkGURTBli8 │ I Can't Make You Love Me │ {4KDyYWR7IpxZ7xrdYbKrqY} │ {AD,AE,AR,AT,AU,BE...}   │
│ 2   │ 7ilWEHob3AYG3lAJlKEpDR │ Baby I'm A Fool          │ {2P1puQXmG48EVLBrHbum1J} │ {}                       │
│ 3   │ 0SuG9kyzGRpDqrCWtgD6Lq │ Give Me Love             │ {6eUKZXaKkcviH0Ku9w2n3V} │ {AD,AE,AR,AT,AU,BE...}   │
│ 4   │ 3K9PY33TKt25UXX6YymFQq │ To Be Alone With You     │ {4MXUO7sVCaFgFjoTI5ox5c} │ {}                       │
```

In the information_schema.columns table, these columns are marked as the ARRAY data type, not text.

In Python, I was able to use the psycopg2 package to read in array columns with no problems in a pandas dataframe. Is there a way to read array type columns in Julia dataframes without using PyCall?

The only solution I could come up with is to manipulate the columns after loading the data into a dataframe.

```
import DataFrames, DBInterface
const jdf = DataFrames;
const dbi = DBInterface;
. . .
df = dbi.execute(conn, stmt) |> jdf.DataFrame;
df[!, "available_markets"] = split.(replace.(df[!, "available_markets"], r"[{}]" => ""), ",");
```

This gets me what I need but I would prefer to have the column already loaded as an Array{String, 1} data type.

Comment: Can you do it in other language? If you read any composite data structure from database it should always read as text. The you should parse the structure to julia readable structure.

Comment: Consider LibPQ.jl it's Tables.jl compatible (and thus DataFrames.jl compatible). Https://invenia.github.io/LibPQ.jl/stable/